# How to access a specific method within a class in Python

Tags: file, class, methods, import

```
[Running Python 2.7 on MacOSX]
```

Hello there,

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and really need it sorted. If someone could write an example of how this possibly could be done, I would be *really* grateful.

Basically, what I am trying to do is access a **specific** method from within a class. So this class is being called from another file, so that this method can be called. *However, I do not want any other method to be called, only this particular method.*

I've tried to read through documentation to different posts around here. Still didn't find anything that seemed to help, perhaps I just don't grasp it very well. I'll look forward to suggestions - I will choose the best answer, I'm close to finishing what I'm working on but as it's an assignment I can't really post it here, and this is one of the last things stopping me.

Thank you in advance for any help!